# jQuery : get the name of a specific folder

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript: Listing File and Folder Structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10774377/javascript-listing-file-and-folder-structure)

I have a folder who contains two other folders. I know the name of one of them, but not the second. Is it possible to get this name with jQuery or Javascript ? My script file is on the root (on the main/parent folder).

example:

```
main_folder (name = theme)
-> children_folder_1 (name = origin)
-> children_folder_2 (name = ?)
```

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10774377/javascript-listing-file-and-folder-structure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean JavaScript code running in a web browser and figuring out the name of the other folder on your server, no, there's no (reasonable) way to do that.

(The *un*reasonable way would be to do a bunch of ajax requests with guesses about what the other folder's name was, working through various alphanumeric combinations, etc., handling the 404s until it got lucky. Like I said, unreasonable. And you'd have to have the name of a resource in that folder unless it supported a default document.)