# How can I get a list of images in a folder using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slideshow

I have a folder tree like so:

1. **ProjectFolder**

   - **img**

     - *fjdkslajsd.jpg*
     - *fjowefwask.jpg*
     - *fweoifqadf.jpg*
     - ...
   - **scripts**

     - *script.js*
     - *jquery.js*
   - **stylesheets**

     - *styles.css*
   - *index.html*

The *index.html* file pretty much just links to the scripts and stylesheet, and contains a div to hold my content. What I want to do is have the *script.js* find all the names of the images in the **img** folder and put them in a list so that I can later cycle through the list and display the images one by one. The end result would essentially look like a powerpoint that continuously cycles through the images in the **img** folder and displays them.

I hope that clears up any of your questions, so here's mine... How would I capture a list of strings that contain the names of the images in the **img** folder? I already know how to cycle through the list and display the images, but I have no idea how I would tackle GETTING the list.

Comment: in what environment? the webbrowser?

Comment: This might be relevant to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10774377/javascript-listing-file-and-folder-structure

Answer (score 2):

Unless you have some kind of interface server-side which gives you a parseable structure representing the project folder / file structure, you won't be able to use or handle this information in javascript.

If you have PHP available on your server, you can generate a javascript array using plain output:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var imageList=[<?php
        $dir='/projectdir/img/';
        $files = scandir($dir);
        foreach((array)$files as $file){
           if($file=='.'||$file=='..') continue;
           $fileList[]=$file;
        }
        echo "'".implode("','", $fileList)."'";
    ?>];
</script>
```

After the browser parses this, `imageList` will contain an array of all the files in the given folder. You can then use this array for further processing / handling.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to make a ajax request to a server side script that will give you a list of files from either an arbitrary directory (this could be dangerous) or specifically the images directory (probably the better way to handle it). Once you have the list of files from the server side script, you can use javascript to create the image elements and add them to the DOM once it is ready to be modified.

If you're using PHP, you can use PHP to add each of those images to the page in the appropriate place as well and save yourself an ajax request.

Comment: True, I believe Perl and Python can do the same over a standard Apache web server. I tend to only reference languages that I've used to keep from chewing on my foot if I claim a language does something that it in fact does not do.